# Simplify the following

Tags: calculus, derivatives

$$\frac{(x-2)^2\frac{d}{dx}(x^2-4x)-(x^2-4x)\frac{d}{dx}(x-2)^2}{((x-2)^2)^2}$$

Please simplify this....:/

The answer should be $$\frac{8}{(x-2)^3}$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\frac{(x-2)^2\color{red}{\frac{d}{dx}(x^2-4x)}-(x^2-4x)\color{blue}{\frac{d}{dx}(x-2)^2}}{((x-2)^2)^2}$$

$$= \frac{(x-2)^2\color{red}{(2x-4)}-(x^2 - 4x)\cdot \color{blue}{2(x-2)}}{(x-2)^4}$$

$$= \frac{2(x-2)(x-2)(x-2) - 2x(x-4)\cdot (x-2)}{(x-2)^4}$$

$$ = \frac{2(x-2)^2 - 2x(x-4)}{(x-2)^3}$$

$$ = \frac{2[x^2 - 4x + 4 - (x^2 - 4x)]}{(x-2)^3}$$

$$ = \frac {8}{(x-2)^3}$$

Comment: Great use of color!

Answer (score 5):

Here are a few hints.

First, take the derivaties of the two terms in the numerator.  So you'll need to figure out

$$\frac{d}{dx}(x^2-4x) = ?$$ and $$\frac{d}{dx}[(x-2)^2] = ?$$

After you do that, there should be a factor of $(x-2)$ that you can cancel, which will leave you $(x-2)^3$ in the denominator.

Finally, simplify the numerator.

Answer (score 1):

In your expression you can recognize the derivative of a ratio:
$$\frac{(x-2)^2\frac{d}{dx}(x^2-4x)-(x^2-4x)\frac{d}{dx}(x-2)^2}{((x-2)^2)^2}=\frac{d}{dx}\frac{x^2-4x}{(x-2)^2}=\frac{d}{dx}\frac{(x-2)^2-4}{(x-2)^2}=$$
$$=\frac{d}{dx}\left(1-4(x-2)^{-2}\right)=-4\cdot(-2)(x-2)^{-3}=\frac{8}{(x-2)^3}$$